# How do I change the max segment size on ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: 12.04, networking, server

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 server and the tcp MSS is set too low. How do I change it to 1460? I have tried stopping the network and then using:

sudo echo "1460" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_app_win

The response come back with rnetlink answers: no such file or directory (even though I am looking at the file)
I also tried:

sudo ip ro change default via 98.248.48.146 dev eth0 admvss 1460 mtu 1500
and it also errors out.
Can you help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set too low?  What is it now?  Normally it's 1500 unless you change it.

Comment: `tcp_app_win` is completely unrelated to the MSS. The only values that make sense for `tcp_app_win` are in the interval from 0 through 31.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [sysctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/en/man2/sysctl.2.html) for configure kernel parameters at runtime. Type:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_app_win=1460
```

then check if value as set, with:

```
sudo sysctl -a|grep tcp_app_win
```

the output should be: `net.ipv4.tcp_app_win = 1460`